# Python сравнение объектов

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы

Есть класс:

```
class Circle(Point):
    def __init__(self, r, Point):
        self.r=r
        self.center=Point
    def __lt__(self, other):
        if self.square()<other.square():
            return 'first object smaller than other'
        else:
            return 'first object not smaller than other'
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if self.square()==other.square():
            return 'first object smaller than other'
    def square(self):
        return ((self.r**2)*math.pi)
```

Создаю несколько объектов этого класса `c1=Circle(4, Point(1.5,1)) c2=Circle(1, Point(1,1)) c3=Circle(100, Point(1,1))`. Я хочу поместить эти объекты в лист, чтобы потом выполнить сортировку этого листа (list.sort()) и вывести объекты по возрастанию, как это сделать? На данный момент `cirl_1.sort()` возвращает None.

Comment: list.sort всегда возвращает None

Answer (score 4):

Методы сравнения должны возвращать `bool`, а не `str`.

```
import math

class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class Circle:
    def __init__(self, r, Point):
        self.r = r
        self.center = Point
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Circle cx={self.center.x} cy={self.center.y} r={self.r}>'
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.square() < other.square()
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.square() == other.square()
    def square(self):
        return ((self.r**2)*math.pi)

c1=Circle(400, Point(1.5,1))
c2=Circle(1, Point(1,1))
c3=Circle(100, Point(1,1))

lst = [c1, c2, c3]
print(lst)
print(sorted(lst))
```

Результат:

```
[<Circle cx=1.5 cy=1 r=400>, <Circle cx=1 cy=1 r=1>, <Circle cx=1 cy=1 r=100>]
[<Circle cx=1 cy=1 r=1>, <Circle cx=1 cy=1 r=100>, <Circle cx=1.5 cy=1 r=400>]
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам не нужно присваивать list.sort() какой либо переменной, достаточной его выполнить:

```
c1=4
c2=3
c3=5

circle_1 = [c1, c2, c3]
print(circle_1)
circle_1.sort()
print(circle_1)
```

Выход:

```
[4, 3, 5]
[3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: А если объект c1 это элемент класса circle, тоже самое c2,c3 и отсортировать их все нужно по r (c1=Circle(4, Point(1.5,1)) для c1 это 4, для c2 это 1, для c3 это 100), через лист? Тоесть мне не понятно как отсортировать объекты по 1 атрибуту.